# Showing popup window for few seconds in iphone xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uialertview, nstimer, popupwindow

I have an application where popup window comes showing please wait until and unless process gets completed.

But sometimes i get pretty good speed and application just flick that pop-up window, it doesn't look good. So I want to show that pop up window for few seconds like say 3 seconds. I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Anks

Comment: how do you hide the view when your process finishes?

Comment: hmm [self.view removefromsuperview];

Comment: You will still get times when the processing is only just longer than your allotted wait time and then get the flickering. Animate the disappearing with a fade out and then it doesn't appear too abrupt whenever it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup can be simple view that you pop on screen or add as subview or an alertView. You can hide it with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodToHideView) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

That's ofc in condition that the popup is still open.

Answer (score 0):

use a timer and hide window if timer exceed beyond count 3/...use NSTimer

Answer (score 0):

use NSTimer for this and you will be done

Answer (score 0):

Try

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];